# Can secure boot be enabled on Azure virtual machines using ARM template deployment?

Tags: azure, security, azure-resource-manager

As part of our development process we are required to certify our drivers against the Microsoft HLK/HCK test suites. As our testing infrastructure exists in Azure, I need a method to enable secure boot via ARM template (or other method) on the Azure Marketplace based VMs.

I have scoured the interwebs for references to this process, but was unable to find anything.

Is there an option anywhere in the latest ARM versions that would allow me to secure boot enable my Server 2016-Datacenter Azure VMs?

Answer (score 0):

https://argonsys.com/learn-microsoft-cloud/library/secure-boot-on-virtual-machines/

This could be enabled on the Guest OS level if the powershell run upon the Guest OS goes through. If not it could be within the ARM GitHub Schema prior to being documented. If not Microsoft may need to intervene on a low severity task.